# Ruby on Rails on Windows XP CTRL+C in console not stopping mongrel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, windows-xp

I am currently in the process of learning Ruby on Rails. I have been following the [Learning Rails](http://buildingwebapps.com/course) podcast and screencasts.

I've run into a problem, well more of an annoyance. Every time the screencast has me kill the mongrel server I am forced to close the console window because CTRL+C isnt killing it as it should. I then have to open a new console window, navigate to my rails app and issue a 'ruby script/server' command to restart it.

What I am looking for is possibly a reason for this, a way to fix it or other suggestions to make this process faster and/or less annoying. Or even possibly a batch file or shortcut to open a cmd window right to where I need it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> instead. It will stop the server.

[image]

Comment: I ran into this problem too.  Ctrl+Pause/Break worked wonderfully.  This seems to be a new issue with rails 2.3.2.  I just upgraded from 2.1.1.  If I change my environment to 2.3.2 Ctrl+C doesn't work, change it back to 2.2.2, works great.

Comment: I was having the same problem with a Python script running in Windows CMD, Ctrl+Pause did the trick

Comment: I don't have a Pause/Break key on my Dell Laptop. What shall I do?

Comment: nice one :D ctrl+c is once again broken in rails 3.2.1 tx for the save :D

Comment: +1 Using Rails 3.2.1 in Windows 7 64bit CTRL+C didn't work but CTRL+Pause/Break did.

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> force closes the server. It's not normal. Anyways my Dell notebook does not have the key.

So use this:
instead of `rails s` use `ruby script/rails s`.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will work perfectly with that. Tested it.

Comment: Works brilliantly with Dell XPS14 - verified.

Answer (score 2):

It's a known issue and here is the patch:https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2088-mongrel-not-being-stopped-with-ctrl-c-under-windows

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can happen if you are catching Exception and not re raising it. SIG-INT would be caught there and ultimately not kill the process.

Comment: how can i check if this is happening. i know i did not explicitly add an exception catch for SIG-INT or any other exception (yet) as I am just following a basic tutorial

Comment: Just search your project for "rescue Exception".

Answer (score 1):

If all fails, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, open the task manager and just kill the ruby process ;)
[image: Ruby process]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Windows as well, so can't help you in fixing the Ctrl+C issue. But, I can point you towards [Windows PowerToys' Open Command Window Here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx) - it adds "Open Command Window Here" to your Explorer window, it's a requirement for development (of any sort) on Windows machines.

Comment: Well, thats definitely a start. I can't imagine we are the only two people on SO that have used Rails on windows and have a problem with CTRL+C killing the server.

Comment: I use windows (xp) and have no problem killing my server.

Answer (score 0):

If you start mongrel a little different like this:

```
$ cd myrailsapp
$ mongrel_rails start
```

then you can stop it like this:

```
$ mongrel_rails stop
```

You can get more info [here](http://mongrel.rubyforge.org/web/mongrel/files/README.html). This might be interesting to: [Mongrel as a service](http://mongrel.rubyforge.org/wiki/Win32)

Answer (score 0):

Check your rails version and use

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>+<kbd>pause/break</kbd>  for 2.3.2
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>   for 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

After you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, send a request to the server by refreshing your browser page where you had it open. The command prompt will now say `Exiting` and let you back to the command line.